# Azure AD users data retrieval issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I'm trying to get some users related data from Azure AD, using AD Graph API or  MS Graph API, but having trouble getting some specific data needed.
I need to get data like:
LastPasswordChangeTimestamp
StrongAuthenticationRequirements (for MFA)
StrongPasswordRequired
PasswordNeverExpires

All the client/API calls doesn't return this data.
The only way I found to retrieve this data is to use Azure cmdlts. The cmdlt to use is "Get-MsolUser".
Before using this cmdlt, the "Connect-MsolService" cmdlt needs to be executed in order to perform the login process.
According to the cmdlt documentation,  found in the next link,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/connect-msolservice?view=azureadps-1.0

there are several ways to enter the credentials required:
1. Entering a user data (user, password) in a popup window.
2. Reading the data from a PSCredential object, that loads the data from a file.
3. Supplying 2 access tokens.

The first 2 options are not valid for us, leaving us with the third option.
We use an Application to access the Azure API, so after creating the required
tokens and supplying it to the cmdlt, there were no users returned. The Application was granted permission to read directory data.
If on the other hand, I sing it with a popup, supplying user credentials, I do get a list of the users with the additional data we need.
So, to summarize our problem -

We need a way to execute an MSOL type cmdlts using Registered App credentials (i.e., AppId and key) that we get from our clients in the onboarding process or an API/client call to retrieve the data.